# How do I draw and write comments in VSCode?

Tags: drawing, visual-studio-code

I am looking for way to draw and write comments on top of my code in Visual Studio Code.

Like how it can be done in Adobe Reader.

Comment: I do not know of any way to include images, sorry. Comments should be in the relevant programming language.

Answer (score 0):

See Menu item "Edit"/"Toggle Line Comment" or "Edit/Toggle Block Comment".
There you can also find the key combinations to comment or uncomment a line or a block.

How to put comments into a code file depends on the type of file, which is often governed by the filename extension (.e.g. `.sh`), or by the first line of the file. If the first line starts with `#!` (these two bytes of the file are called "shebang") it says "following these these two characters, there is a call to a program to run this file".

If you want to use a  documentation generator such as javadoc, phpdoc, jsdoc ... this is often the task of VSCode *extensions*. No general advice is possible, as far as I know.